# the input textfield is blocked by the keyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, keyboard, textfield

I have developed a game using C++ and cocos-2dx. I want to compile it in Xcode. But it's found that the UIview did not go up when I input some text like password during login, so the textfield is being blocked by the keyboard. How can I solve this? 
Thanks all.

Comment: Add your tried code

Comment: I didn't code anything to solve this problem... totally no idea